# PDE question: heat equation (third order??)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am familiar with the usual heat equation, however, my lecturer gave me this problem and it does not look like anything I have ever seen (in my whole entire life and I am not just being dramatic).

$\frac {\partial T}{\partial t} =\frac {1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} ( r^2 \frac {\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2} + \frac2r\frac {\partial T}{\partial r})$

Okay, I realized that I cannot possibly expand it out because it will be very messy and it will contain a third order equation (and also someone told me not to expand it out). I was thinking of substitution however I have not found a suitable substitute that I can work here. Any ideas?

Comment: You write : <<my lecturer gave me this problem >>. But you don't say what exactly is the wording of the problem. Only giving an equation is not enough. It is asked for the general solution of the PDE ? is it asked for a particular solution according to some given conditions ? Is it asked for an answer to an other question without need to solve the PDE ? Or something else ?